# Android Reader Regarding the issue of automatic scrolling:

Tags: scroll

Regarding the issue of automatic scrolling:

How does the automatic reading function in tomato novels work?

Can you please tell me where to look at the code?

**automatic scrolling：slow、standard、fast.**

thks~

I want the code，or  you can provide guidance~

thks!